# how to do hibernate mapping for table or view without a primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate and no PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk)

Anyone knows how to do hibernate mapping for table or view without a primary key?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't think Hibernate allows mapping a table without a primary key...think about how Hibernate would perform updates without a column that can uniquely identify a row.

I guess a work-around would be to use a composite key with all columns, but you are much better off adding a primary key.

Comment: I think you are correct here. Also the composite key (of all columns) would still need to be primary, so your better off making a more reasonable composite key or choosing a uniquely identifying column as the primary key.

Comment: I don't know that it matters too much in a read-only situation (wrt udpates).

Comment: so,when I select from a view without a primary key ,and dont want t oupdate view what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

I would do this only when you are reading data (not writing it). When you have a DB like oracle, you can have statements like

```
select DOKUMENT.*, ROWID from DOKUMENT
```

→ and thus, you can add this statement into the Hibernate mapping:

```
<id column="ROWID" type="string" />
```

subsequently, you define all other columns as

```
<property...
```

When you use the reverse engineering Wizard, you can

1. remove the composite-key tag,
2. search and replace key-property for property and
3. insert above line

Comment: You'll have to change accordingly your insert/update code