# How is unique constraint applied from more than one table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have 3 tables is shown this tables:
table A

```
 A(
        code1
        .
        .
        .
    )
```

table B

```
B(
    code2
    .
    .
    .
)
```

table C

```
C(
    code3
    .
    .
    .
)
```

I want to be unique between code1,code2,code3 of this tables.
How do i recieve to my goal in oracle?
Does any syntax of oracle exist about this problem?

Comment: Unique constraints only apply to one table.  Although you can do this with triggers, I would question your database design, and suggest alternatives that don't have this issue.

Comment: What is your idea about oracle's View from this tables and apply this constraint to it?do it possible?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668146/how-to-add-a-primary-key-on-a-oracle-view.

Comment: Finished editing, you can check the solution now

Comment: Tables needs redesigning

Answer (score 1):

Based on materialized view.

P.s.
The code is not validated.
I currently have access only to oracle XE 11gR2, so I'm not able to use the materialized view log feature.

---

```
create table A   (code int primary key);
create table B   (code int primary key);
create table C   (code int primary key);

create materialized view log on a with primary key;
create materialized view log on b with primary key;
create materialized view log on c with primary key;

create materialized view ABC_MV
refresh fast
as
          select code from A
union all select code from B
union all select code from C
;

alter table ABC_MV add unique (code);
```

Comment: This is a clever solution.  Do you know if it actually works in practice?  Materialized views have different refresh options.  It would seem that the constraint (if allowed) would break the materialized view but still allow the data to go into the underlying tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, clever solution, but not mine. I saw it few weeks ago on SO but since it was a different use case involving a single table, I answered and didn't flag it as duplicate. The refresh on demand indeed causing the MV to break, but this is not surprising. I assume that refresh on commit will do the job but as I said I currently can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_check
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT attribute FROM table2
        WHERE attribute = :NEW.attribute
    ) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
        'Already exist in table2');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

You can modify it to check in more tables as well.

Comment: I know to add a trigger but is not there a solution without trigger?

Comment: The best solution is to use trigger. There is no other good way to do that. Of course you can redesign, maybe you don't need 3 tables.

Answer (score -1):

Using a 4th table

---

```
create table ABC (tab char(1) not null ,code int primary key, unique (tab,code));

create table A   (tab char(1) as ('A') virtual not null,code int primary key,foreign key (tab,code) references ABC(tab,code));
create table B   (tab char(1) as ('B') virtual not null,code int primary key,foreign key (tab,code) references ABC(tab,code));
create table C   (tab char(1) as ('C') virtual not null,code int primary key,foreign key (tab,code) references ABC(tab,code));
```

---

```
insert into ABC (tab,code) values ('A',1);
insert into A (code) values (1);
insert into A (code) values (1);
```

> [Code: 1, SQL State: 23000]  ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.SYS_C0012834) violated

```
insert into B (code) values (1);
```

> [Code: 2291, SQL State: 23000]  ORA-02291: integrity constraint
>   (SYS.SYS_C0012839) violated - parent key not found

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution  force me when a record is inserted to any of A or B or C,it is inserted to 4th table too