# EF not recognizing PK of view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, view, primary-key

I am using Oracle as the DB, VS2012, and EF 5.0.

I know the table has a PK (Composite Key) and I create a view with

```
create view v_table_name as select * from table_name
```

When I try to add the view to EF, it says there is not PK and makes the object read only. I have tried to add a PK to the view but it tells me that the `table can have only on primary key`.

I used the following

```
ALTER VIEW V_TABLE_NAME 
ADD CONSTRAINT V_V_TABLE_NAME_PK PRIMARY KEY (DRSY, DRRT, DRKY) DISABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Any idea why EF is not recognizing the PK?

Comment: This actually seems to be working ok

Answer (score 1):

Because EF doesn't infer PKs for views, as far as I know.

You don't actually have to add the PK to the view if there is a PK on `table_name`.

You just need to [tell EF what the key column(s) are.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try below **without NOVALIDATE**

```
ALTER VIEW V_TABLE_NAME 
ADD CONSTRAINT V_V_TABLE_NAME_PK PRIMARY KEY (DRSY, DRRT, DRKY) DISABLE ;
```

[**NOVALIDATE Issue**](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8806498660292)

You can do it by following below mentioned link.

[**adding primary key to Oracle view**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041308/adding-primary-key-to-sql-view?rq=1)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: @CraigStuntz yes but with NOVALIDATE key.May be that is the problem.I have updated my post.Will see ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the underlying tables queried in the view have PKs or at least a non-nullable column(s) that you can designate in the view.  If you use the solution provided by [sampath]: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077309/sampath but the columns are nullable EF won't create an object based on the view.

In this case can designate the key in DbContext.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityName>().HasKey(e => new {e.KeyCol1, e.KeyCol2,     e.KeyCol3});
```