# Oracle SQL - ALTER VIEW : ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add a primary key constraint to my column, but Oracle gives me the following error message:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

SQL:

```
ALTER VIEW view_my_departments
add CONSTRAINT department_id_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (department_id);
```

Comment: you cant add constraints to a view. only to tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding primary key to sql view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041308/adding-primary-key-to-sql-view)

Answer (score 3):

Views do not have constraints.  A view is simply a query that is saved with a name.  Because it's a query, it returns a result set and is thus interchangeable with a table in terms of queries.

However, there is no actual data persisted in it.  Only tables have data and thus tables may have constraints.  Find out which table contains department_id (probably called department I'm guessing?) and add the constraint to that using.

```
ALTER TABLE department
add CONSTRAINT department_id_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (department_id);
```

Querying a table is like using a sub-query.

If "myview" is defined as:

```
select r.a, ro.b, u.c
from registration r
inner join roster ro on r.roster_id = ro.roster_id
inner join user u on u.user_id = ro.user_id
```

Then the database will interpret the following query

```
select a, b, c
from myview
where x = 1
```

as

```
select a, b, c
from (select r.a, ro.b, u.c
      from registration r
      inner join roster ro on r.roster_id = ro.roster_id
      inner join user u on u.user_id = ro.user_id)
where x = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, they must be written with disable clause as it cannot be validated.

So try,

```
ALTER VIEW view_my_departments
add CONSTRAINT department_id_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (department_id) disable;
```