# Hibernate one-to-one mapping on another entity acting as primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

So consider the following 2 tables:

table: User

```
id (pk)
...
```

and table UserProfile:

```
UserProfile
user_id(pk, and fk from User.id. fk is named profile_user_fk)
...
```

given this tables, I have the entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private UserProfile profile;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    public UserProfile getProfie() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(UserProfile  p) {
        profile = p;
    }
...
}

And the User class:
@Entity
@Table(name="UserProfile")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="profile_user_fk")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
...
}
```

I don't want to add an extra column in UserProfile because I think this column is meaningless. User.id should be sufficient to indicate the identity of UserProfile records.

So I supposed the @OneToOne annotations will tell hibernate user is a pk and also fk and should refer to User.id for its own id; however executing the code shows:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: xxx.UserProfile
```

Apparently what I thought was wrong - but Ｉ've no idea what can I do to **fix it without altering the schema.**

Any helps please. Thanks!

Comment: Error itself says `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: xxx.UserProfile` you need to add primary key column in `UserProfile` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **error**

```
No identifier specified for entity: xxx.UserProfile
```

**says**

```
In your Entity class (UserProfile), you have not defined a primary key. You must specify 
either @Id annotation or an @EmbeddedId annotation. Bcoz, every class defined as Entity
with @Entity annotation, needs an @Id or @EmbeddedId property.
```

Modify your **UserProfile** class as below :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserProfile")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {

    private long uProfileId;
    private User user;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "uProfileId", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public long getUProfileId() {
        return uProfileId;
    }

    public void setUProfileId(long uProfileId) {
        this.uProfileId = uProfileId;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="profile_user_fk")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Read:** [@Entity & @Id and @GeneratedValue Annotations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm)

---

**Entity Class without Primary Key :**

If you don't want to add primary key in **UserProfile** table then you can use **@Embedded & @Embeddable annotations** or **`<component>`** tag in xml mapping. For more explanation on this look at below posts:-

1. [Using `<component>` or @Embedded & @Embeddable annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773939/hibernate-documentation-parent-child-type-relationship/26778662#26778662)
2. [Hibernate and no PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk)
3. [Hibernate/persistence without @Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925818/hibernate-persistence-without-id)

Comment: so this means I have to also add a column in UserProfile, which I think is useless but only to comply with Hibnerate? As I said the fk to user.id should be sufficient as a pk of UserProfile too. Is it a way of working it out without changing db schema? Thanks!

Comment: Since you have created `UserProfile` class as `Entity` class, you must have to add `Id` in it. If you don't want to alter ur database table then, you can use **@Embedded** & **@Embeddable** annotations or **`<component>`** tag in case of mapping with xml file. See my updated answer.