# Hibernate Documentation: Parent/Child type relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, documentation

In the Hibernate documentation, there is [such](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch23.html) a sentence:

> The default semantics of a one-to-many association in Hibernate are
>   much less close to the usual semantics of a parent/child relationship
>   than those of a composite element mapping.

I found this sentence to be very confusing, can somebody explain what it means? Also, on the [Best Pratices](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch26.html) page, you will find

> Write fine-grained classes and map them using `<component>`

I'm not sure what to make of these. Is mapping using `<component>` when you use Hibernate API instead of JPA? How does it translate to JPA if this is Hibernate specific?

Comment: Look at my answer. I tried to explain the above queries in ur question. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1 :** *The default semantics of a one-to-many association in Hibernate are much less close to the usual semantics of a parent/child relationship than those of a composite element mapping.* **means** :-

Suppose, you have two classes named, `A` & `B`. A has *primary key* `aId`, which is *foreign key* in B. Then in this case, when you map them using Hibernate, *A can be called as parent of B &/or B is a child of A.* Because, B is dependent on A for it's primary key. If you try to add entry in `B` class before `A` then it gives error something like `ConstraintViolationException`.

---

**Case 2 :** Write fine-grained classes and map them using **`<component>`** :-

The word **component in Hibernate** refers to a contained object in another object & not as a separate entity in database. Word **component** describes **composition** in Hibernate. More precisely, it means create an entity in database table with two separate objects in Java.

**For example :** You have a `Person` object containing various fields namely, `id, firstName, lastName, address, age, etc.` Then you can create a **single table** in database as

```
drop table if exists Person
create table Person(
     id int,
     firstName varchar(50),
     lastName varchar(50),
     street varchar(50),
     state varchar(50),
     zipcode int(8),
     age int(3)
);
```

Now, you need to create **two pojo classes** namely, `Person` & `Address`.

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private Address address;

    //getter/setter
}

public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String state;
    private int zipCode;

    //getter/setter
}
```

To introduce composition in this scenario you can use **`<component>`** tag in case of **XML configuration** or **@Embedded & @Embeddable annotations**.

If you create XML file for the Person class then is likely as follows :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Person" table="Person">
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <component name="address" class="Address">
         <property name="street" column="street" type="String"/>
         <property name="state" column="state" type="String"/>
         <property name="zipcode" column="zipcode" type="int"/>
      </component>
      <property name="firstName" column="firstName" type="String"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="lastName" type="String"/>
      <property name="age" column="age" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

On the other hand, using **@Embedded & @Embeddable annotations** in POJO classes as :-

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    //getter/setter
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String state;
    private int zipCode;

    //getter/setter
}
```

The @Embedded annotation is used to specify; the Address entity should be stored in the Person table as a component.

@Embeddable annotation is used to specify; the Address class will be used as a component. 
The Address class cannot have a primary key of its own, it uses the enclosing class primary key.

**Persisting Person In DB :**
While performing insertion operation on database. You need to first create an object of Address class & then Person class.

```
Address address = new Address("ABC Road", "MH", "440022");
Person person = new Person("A", "Z", 10, address);
session.save(person);
```

To check data in Person table you can fire below query :-

```
mysql> select id, firstName, lastName, street, state from Person;
---------------------------------------------------
| id | firstName | lastName |   street  |  state  |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 | A         | Z        |  ABC Road |   MH    |
|  2 | B         | Y        |  XYZ Road |   MP    |
---------------------------------------------------
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

---

**EDIT : CASE 1 vs CASE 2 (Association vs Composition) :**

Case 1 represents Association whereas, Case 2 represents Composition. **Association is meant to represent relationship between two distinct entities,** such as one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many. On the other hand, composition is commonly known as **HAS A** relationship between two entities, where one entity is a **part of** another entity, **if the contained entity cannot exist without the existence of container entity**.

**For More Explaination :** [Association, Aggregation and Composition](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shivprasadk/3-important-concepts-association-aggregation-and-composi/)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. In case 1, could you also contrast that to **composite element mapping**

Comment: @Dkyc I have updated my answer with difference in Association & Composition. Have a look at it.