# how to set a @entity without @id element?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accesos")
public class Acceso implements Serializable {
    /** */
    @Column(name = "idUser")
    private String idUser;
    /** */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idArea")
    private Area area;
    /** */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idRol")
    private Rol rol;
```

But I get this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com...Acceso

How can I set this bean? What I need is based on the user ID get all the ROL-AREA that he has access.

I tried change the `@Entity` to `@Embedded`, but when I make the search no result is returned, and even in the log is no SQL sentence executed.

Comment: An entity must always have a primary key; you cannot create an entity without a primary key (id).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate/persistence without @Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925818/hibernate-persistence-without-id)

Answer (score 6):

You have to have an identity for each bean, there is no way around. You can however use a combined key, if none of your fields is unique.

If the combination of all your fields is unique, then try to annotate *all fields* with `@Id`. Take as few fields as possible, but as many as required to make the combination unique.

Comment: Or all **relevant** fields. As I speculated on another answer, I expect the primary key should be (`idUser`, `area`) in which case you would put `@Id` on both those fields but not on `rol`. See the [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e2471) for more details.

Comment: Yes, the answer was to set the 3 fields as @Id, because they are foreign keys, thank you!

Comment: Caution: That they are foreign keys doesn't automatically mean that all three are part of your primary key. Think of the primary as being what actually identifies this particular `Acceso`. Can there be more than one row with the same (user,area) combination? My gut says `rol` should not be part of your primary key but maybe I'm wrong--if you can have multiple `rol`s for a user+area combination, then `rol` is part of your id.

Comment: @Slartidan  "You can however use a combined key, if none of your fields is unique", I didn't understand this combined key concept. Can you explain it a bit? My table allows duplicate rows and it doesn't have a primary key or unique key in it. How can i map this table to a JPA entity?

Answer (score 1):

JPA Specifications state that all Entities must have an identifier ([JSR 317, section 2.4](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1433777134_fb873e2fd2e8b2d5faee8e06fa801896)). It can be a single column or a composite key.

You can either put an `idAcceso` identifier in the `Acceso` entity or not make `Acceso` an entity but rather a "component" (which is the purpose of the `@Embeddable` annotation). Components do not require an ID but cannot be queried separately (i.e. you cannot do `select a from Acceso a` but rather you need to query for `User` and then use the accessor method `user.getAccesos()`.

You cannot substitute `@Entity` with `@Embedded` in this context.

```
@Embeddable
public class Acceso {
  // ...
}

@Entity
public class User {
  @Id protected String id;
  // ...

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
    name="USER_ACCESSES",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
  protected Set<Acceso> accesos = new HashSet<Acceso>();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't have an id specified and you MUST so add @Id annotation onto idUser

```
@Id
@Column(name = "idUser")
private String idUser;
```

Comment: Except that, based on his comments, I doubt he'd want idUser to be the primary key of this table. Sounds more like idUser is a foreign key into a user table.

Comment: Yeah I know but it is that or an EmbeddedId (composite primary key)

Comment: It *sounds* like it needs to be a composite key; I think a combination of (idUser, area) would do the trick.