# SpringBoot "not an entity"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new to Hibernate and SpringBoot. My projects deals with a search engine that is composed of 2 independent modules + 1 base module common to both (where the `IndexSetup` class resides).

There is one module for indexing (JavaFx) and the other one for searching via the web browser (Spring Boot).

The indexing module involves an "IndexSetup" class that has the details on how / what should be indexed :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IndexSetups")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class IndexSetup {
  private final SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // For H2 AUTO is required to auto increment the id
  public int getId() {
      return id.get();
  }

  //... other properties, getters and setters

 }
```

So it works great, the data is indexed and can be retrieved via a search method within the indexing module.

However when I run the Spring Boot server and do the same search I get 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class my.package.IndexSetup

By the way there is no build error, and before the modules were parts of a parent pom project, they were in the same project with the server class in a subfolder, and it worked. I decided to separate them for convenience during developpment and to offer two independent modules in production.

So why did it work when everything was under the same Netbeans project and now that the modules are in 2 different subfolders (but in the same group id package "my.package") I get this "Not an entity" and what should I do to solve this, where should I look at ?

Please note : I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780341/do-i-need-class-elements-in-persistence-xml) without success ("null pointer exception, cannot load the database").

**Edit 1:** 
I also tried to add `@EntityScan` following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-entity-scan) but I still get `Not an entity: class my.package.IndexSetup` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"my.package"} )
public class ServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

**Edit 2 :**
The architecture of the project is like :

```
- Parent project (my.package)
  -Module Base (with IndexSetup class)
  -Module Indexing (that depends on Base)
  -Module Server (that also depends on Base)
```

The parent pom.xml reads like the following :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>my.package</groupId>
<artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<!--According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665936/maven-how-to-build-multiple-independent-maven-projects-from-one-project-->

<modules>
    <module>Base</module> <!-- Common resources which is a dependency in Indexer and Server -->
    <module>Indexer</module> <!-- Indexing part with JavaFx-->
    <module>Server</module> <!-- Server (spring boot) part of -->
</modules>
<name>MyApp</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Edit 3:**
The problem originates from when the table to look at is specified:

```
Root<IndexSetup> from = criteriaQuery.from(IndexSetup.class);
```

Looking at [hibernate sources](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/internal/MetamodelImpl.java) `not an entity` is thrown whenever `entityType == null`. **So I don't gather why the entity type is null here whereas it works outside of SpringBoot ?**

**Edit 4:**
If I remove `SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);` from the Server class' main method then the same call which was causing the issue ie :

```
LocalDatabase.getInstance(false) // no GUI
            .getAllIndexSetups();
```

now works picobello. Of course it does not solve anything since I still need SpringBoot for the search! So for me it means that Spring Boot does not understand the hibernate configuration. I opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813610/why-does-my-entity-does-not-work-with-springboot-although-it-works-without) to introduce the problem more accurately.

Any help appreciated,

Comment: @Justas you're right the id field is not marked with @Id. However the @Id mark is on the `getId` method because  `id` is a `SimpleIntegerProperty` (JavaFx). So it was the trick to use SimpleIntegerProperty with hibernate. Do you thinks this is causing the issue ?

Comment: Have you tried removing @Entity? Why do you need it? Or try adding @Id on id.

Comment: Every entity must have identifier/primary key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712842/how-to-set-a-entity-without-id-element

Comment: Why do you need entity and hibernate for indexing? Hibernate is ORM to facilitate accessing relational database, not to query index.

Comment: @Justas the user can add IndexSetup (with index name, data to index, enabled ...). I store these IndexSetups in a database, and then process them one by one with solr. At search time I call a search function of mine (via SolrJ) on each index : `givenIndex.search(params)`. That's why I need to get the list of IndexSetups at search time.

Comment: @Justas I've added where the `@Id` actually is (ie on the getId since id is a JavaFx property not an int).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it happened that I did not use correctly SpringBoot capabilities. Here are the steps I followed. Please remember the architecture of the project :

```
- Parent maven project (my.package)
 |-Module Base (with IndexSetup class and [initialy] hibernate.cfg.xml in /resources. It also had in the beginning LocalDatabase class to access to the local db via hibernate)
 |-Module Indexing (that depends on Base)
 |-Module Server (that also depends on Base)
 |-Database file (myLocalDB)
```

1) First I removed `hibernate.cfg.xml` from Base and dropped it into resources of the Indexing module. I did it because SpringBoot has its own configuration mechanism. I also removed LocalDatabase class from Base (since it would not be needed by SpringBoot) and dropped it too in the Indexing Module (where it is used indeed).

2) Following [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html] I added `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` to the Server module pom.xml.

3) Following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) I created a JPA Repository `IndexSetupRepository` with barely a single line of code :

```
public interface IndexSetupRepository extends CrudRepository<IndexSetup, Integer> {
```

}

4) In the Server `application.properties` I added those lines :

```
# Embedded database configuration
# The embedded database file is one level above the Server folder (ie directly within the parent project)
# we use the auto server mode to be able to use the database simultaneously in the indexer and the server
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:../myLocalDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=myName
# This parameter helped me discover that SpringBoot was not targetting the right table name.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

5) As SpringBoot was telling me it could not find table named `index_setup` (see [camel case converted to _](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087626/entity-class-name-is-transformed-into-sql-table-name-with-underscores)), I had to add this line to the application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

6) Now as I got "Entity not managed", I eventually added `@EntityScan` annotation to the Server main class as many of you advised me to do.

```
@EntityScan("my.package.Entities")
```

*Please note that `@EntityScan` should point to the folder containing the entity class not the entity class itself ie `@EntityScan("my.package.Entities.IndexSetup")` did not work.*

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add to your @EntityScan annotation package of your entities within second project/module

Comment: Thanks @Emil Hotkowski but it did not work (see my edit).

Comment: it actually did work after I changed many things among which `@EntityScan` as I detail in my answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad it helped : )

Answer (score 1):

As first, some checking :

- Is all your configuration only built with annotations in ServerApplication or any Java class, or are there any others external configurations in XML / YML files ? Maybe look for conflicts. We do prefer to not mix XML with annotation configuration, if possible.
- Try to remove `@Serializable` (not really mandatory).
- Try to move your entity in your root package (just as a test).
- Check if the package which export `@Entity` is correct.

Question : what are you calling "module", it is a subpackage or Maven module or another thing ? Could we have the configuration of package names about this ?

**Edit** :

- In the case of a multi-modules project, did you follow recommendations from [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) about multi-modules projets ? Did you import the Spring BOM (or starter) in your submodules and did you test the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/) ?
- Can you provide your `application.properties` (or `application.yml` whatever) with your datasource configuration ? You should check if your datasource (and JPA, driver class, ...) is correctly defined ; see [spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

Comment: Thanks @cactuschibre, I will try your suggestions. Module is Maven module (see the parent pom.xml that I added in my edit).

Comment: I removed `implements serializable` as also explained [here](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/do-i-have-to-use-serializable-for-jpa-and-hibernate-entities/176) without change.

Comment: I moved the IndexSetup class to a subfolder named `Entities`, updated the hibernate.cfg.xml accordingly (otherwise I get NPE) but I still get `Not an entity`. There is no problem with the indexer module which can use this entity flawlessly.

Comment: Great links @cactuschibre! No I haven't followed those links yet, but I'll do now and retry! There is only `server.port=8081` in `application.properties`.

Comment: Eventually I got it working. I will write how I did which is a mix of your hints some others' ones and many other SO questions! I've learned a lot, thank you!