# How to create hibernate mapping for AS/400 file without unique key?

Tags: java, hibernate, ibm-midrange

I am currently working on a Java project involving building interface to read and write from an AS/400 file using hibernate. The file has a key list, but is not unique, i.e. there are multiple records with identical keys in it. If the Java interface is to retrieve a list of records with the same key list from this file, how should the hibernate mapping look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591255/hibernate-without-primary-key

Comment: Duplicate of [Hibernate and no PK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk) as well as [Hibernate without Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591255/hibernate-without-primary-key) and possibly others.