# entity without Id in hibernate, possible or not?

Tags: hibernate

I am just want to know is id element is necessary in hibernate.I know it's good to have a primary or composite primary for each relation but i am just want to know if it's possible or not.If yes can some one please give me an example.

Comment: Uhh... you could just, I dunno, try it out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate and no PK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk)

Comment: Vaibhav i dont want any tricks and traps,jus want to know if hibernate simply supports this type of entities or not.