# Hibernate - One to Many associations

Tags: java, hibernate

i have two tables, ComputerNode and Connection. ComputerNode has a primary key `nodeid` but Connection do not have one. I can't modify the table schema. How should i create the java POJO if they were to have one-to-many relationship? basically my objective is to do a inner join like this:

```
select * from `ComputerNode` cn inner join `Connection` c on cn.nodeid = c.nodeid
```

Here are the SQL table schema.
ComputerNode table:

```
int nodeid <primary key>;
varchar nodename;
```

Connection table:

```
int nodeid <not primary key>;
varchar connstatus;
```

The relationship between the tables is one-to-many. A computer node can have many connections

I have created two Java POJO classes but i'm not exactly sure about the annotations required. I have read the hibernate tutorial but i don't see explanation on class without a identifier(ie: Connection).

ComputerNode.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ComputerNodes")
public class ComputerNode {

@Id
@Column(name="nodeid")
private int nodeId;

@Column(name="nodename")
private String nodeName;

@OneToMany
private Set<Connection> connections;

.... //getter and setters
}
```

Connection.java

```
//What annotation should i use since this class doesn't have identifier?
public class Connection {

@Column(name="nodeid")
private int nodeId;

@Column(name="connstatus")
private String connStatus;
}
```

What type of class is Connection supposed to be? @Embeddable?
What should I do to create a one-to-many relationship between the two classes?

================

## Update

```
public List<ComputerNode> getComputerNodes() {
    //the query to inner join is:
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ComputerNode as node inner join Connection as conn").list();
}

for (ComputerNode cn : getComputerNodes) {
 System.out.println(cn.getNodeId() + ',' + cn.getNodeName());

 for (Connection c : cn.getConnections) {
   System.out.println(c.getConnStatus());
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `@Id` annotation .. ?

Comment: @Id is only for Entity class. But Connection can't be entity can it?

Comment: Connection should be entity only. I think there should be foreign key for that column you use `@Id` in Connection Entity class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ComputerNode")
public class ComputerNode {

@Id
@Column(name="nodeid")
private int nodeId;

@Column(name="nodename")
private String nodeName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="computerNode")
private Set<Connection> connections;

.... //getter and setters
}
```

Connections:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Connection")
public class Connection {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="nodeid")
private ComputerNode computerNode;

...
}
```

If Connection table doesn't have any primary key, check this solution: [Hibernate and table without PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk)

===========

**Updated**

If you want to select ComputerNode entities use this query:
`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select node from ComputerNode as node").list();`

Comment: i got an error: no identifier specified for entity: org...Connection. For a class to be an Entity, it must have @Id.

Comment: Do you have any primary key in table Connection?

Comment: Connection table doesn't have a primary key. and i can't add one because im not allowed to modify the schema

Comment: ok i set @Id to multiple properties in Connection. But im getting Path expected for join

Comment: Joins use associations between entities. Check that Connection table is entity. Or update your code, please.

Comment: Both the classes are @Entity annotated

Comment: You should use paths in join operations. Look at my updated answer and check [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins)

Comment: sigh. I'm getting unknown column 'connection1_.node.nodeid' in field list

Comment: okay i fixed the unknown column. now im getting Ljava.lang.object: cannot be cast to org....ComputerNode...

Comment: i updated my questions, showing how i query and extract the data

Comment: Updated my answer. Also don't forget for implement correct hashCode() and equals() in entities.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the Connection class to become an entity also, for you to have a relationship between two entity class   just put `@Entity`on top it

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Connection")

public class Connection {  
@ManyToOne()
//this will join the nodeId of ComputerNode entity class to Connection entity class
@JoinColumn(name="nodeId")
private ComputerNode nodeId;

@Column(name="connstatus")     
private String connStatus;

}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: nodeid isnt a primary key in Connection table while it is a primary key in ComputerNode table

Comment: i edited my answer please explain why down vote so that i can fix it tnx in advance

Comment: now i see my answer is the same what @Pavel answer -_-. nice try for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you have to do without `id`.

Maybe this can help...

```
@OneToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinTable(
    name="Connection",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="nodeid")
)
private Set<Connection> connections;
```

best!