# JPA: dealing with Views

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, view, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a Repository to work with Views. The fact is that I'm trying to use the **SimpleJpaRepository** implementation, but I'm getting a lot of errors on execution time because my DTO is not an **@Entity**. It is only a **@Table**, and it seems that this kind of elements are not mapped into the Metamodel of JPA.

This is my DTO:

```
@Table(name = "v_language")
public class VLanguage {

    @Column(name = "isocode")
    private String isocode;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "isdefault")
    private String isdefault;

    // getters and setters
    ...
}
```

I tried to define a customized base repository with minimal functionality (only a findAll() method) with the same implementation of SimpleJpaRepository, but when building the Query it fails when doing:

```
Root<U> root = query.from(domainClass);
```

With this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class es.prodevelop.pui.common.jpa.model.views.dto.VLanguage
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:156)
    at es.prodevelop.pui.common.jpa.configuration.AbstractRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(AbstractRepository.java:213)
    at es.prodevelop.pui.common.jpa.configuration.AbstractRepository.getQuery(AbstractRepository.java:174)
    at es.prodevelop.pui.common.jpa.configuration.AbstractRepository.findAll(AbstractRepository.java:151)
    ...
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the `@Entity` annotation.
please annotate your class and try again.

Comment: Yes I know, but if I set the `@Entity` annotation, I'm forced to set an @Id, and views has no @Id columns. I read about setting a fakeId, but it doesn't work when creating the queries, because JPA includes this column to the query...

Comment: what is the problem with the queries? didnt get it

Comment: you can annotate with @Id all the columns that create the unique key for this view.

Comment: This is the only solution I found, thanks (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7593869/1771308). Nevertheless, I will try to find a more elegant solution... ;)

Comment: that's what i said in my previous comment actually :)